# Using a character array as a file name?

Tags: c++

sorry for the noobish question, but I can not seem to get this to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
const int sz = 24;


int main()
{
char a [sz];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cin >> a[i];

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open(a);

cout << inFile.good() << endl;


return 0;
}
```

This is a smaller version of what I am trying to do, and that is open the inFile stream with .open() and for the file name I am trying to pass a, which is a char array.  I have a file called a.txt in the right directory (I have confirmed this) so I input a.txt, which is read into the a array, but inFile.good() still returns false.  I also do know the array is larger then 5 characters, but I do not think this should affect it.

If any more info is needed let me know.

Comment: You need to null terminate your c string. `a[5] = NULL;`

Comment: Is a.txt present in the same dir as the C program?

Comment: Have you null terminated the array so you can use it as a string?

Comment: Wow that was not smart.  Sorry guys, I was under the impression that an unused elements of the array were counted as null, and it would terminate itself, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yes, variables don't get initialised by themselves, but you could have done so by writing `char a[sz] = "";` then it would have been all zeroed.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the `open` is:

```
void open ( const char * filename, ios_base:openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

as seen the fist argument is a constant string(nul terminated character array). In your case there is no nul character at the end. For this to happen you'll need an array of size one more than the maximum file name size you'll be inputting.

Why not read the character all using just one `cin` ? As:

```
cin >> a;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(a);
```

Or even better use the `String` class to get the user input and then use `c_str()` to get the `const char*` equivalent which can be passed to `open`.

Comment: I did not know you could use cin to directly read things into an array like, thanks for that

Comment: @coaddict - For ifstream and ofstream classes, ios::in and ios::out are automatically and respectively assumed, even if a mode that does not include them is passed as second argument to the open() member function.